# Integrate queue messaging between Linux and Windows

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, message-queue, activemq-classic

I have two systems: HQ on Linux and Active MQ on windows
Both systems need to send and receive message between each other.

Anyone implemented a way of integrating between them?? In this case I would like to have an example

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: Are you just looking for _opinions_ on other people's experiences? If that's the case, this isn't an appropriate question for Stack Overflow (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)). If you have a _specific_ question you'd like to ask, please edit your question and do so :)

Comment: I was looking for an implementation using any technology since I am dealing this issue and couldn't find a way..

Comment: wouldn't the point be to have a message queue solution (active mq or some other) such that producers on windows can add to the queue and consumers on linux can take from the queue? Or do you mean you have 2 existing systems, HQ and ActiveMQ, and you need an application that uses both? You're getting downvotes because your question is unclear.

Comment: I have a HQ in the Linux which need to be able to get messages from the MQ which is on Windows. each application(HQ,MQ) is in different OS/machine. I think it pretty much clear in my question isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS providers in general are not interoperable, because there is no common internal message format, or the connection protocol.

The perfect solution would be unifying the providers, so that both systems use the same (could be different instances — don't know about HQ, but ActiveMQ can send to another ActiveMQ).

If this is not acceptable, you can always write adapters yourself, with message-driven beans. One MDB would listen on an MQ queue, to repack the message and forward to ActiveMQ; the other MDB would do the same other way round. The exact setup and configuration of connection factories and queues depends on the application server.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure the HQ can "speak" with ActiveMQ(and viceserva) straight forward. the other solution is good I guess but will cost latency.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ provides a solution for this scenario, its called a [JMS to JMS bridge](http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html) this allows you to bridge destinations between JMS brokers either inbound, outbound or both.  Have a look at the documentation at the link above.

Comment: Thats sound like an Idea. but that bridge where it will be installed and running? in which machine? (linux/windows)

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation?  You can configure a bridge into you existing ActiveMQ broker via the sample 'Example XBean Configuration' or you can create an app that does the bridging using the spring configuration, etc.  Depends on your specific needs, read the docs, look and the sample configurations and choose a solution that fits your requirements.